# JDBC many-to-one mapping / null pointer exception error

Tags: java, jdbc

Right so I have been working on this project for awhile, and I am using JDBC + JSF.

I currently have 3 DAOs, User, Groups, and UserGroups.

My question would be..how do you establish a relationship between the 3 classes , User, Groups and UserGroups??

In my database, UserGroup is a associative entity, which has IDUSer and IDGroup as a Primary Composite Key.

The relationship between User and UserGroup is 1 to Many. The relationship between Groups and UserGroup is also 1 to Many, with UserGroup having a Many to 1 relation with both User and Groups.

Would this be right if I want to create a relationship between User and UserGroup, Group and UserGroup??

```
public class UsuariousGrupos {

Integer id_usuario;
Integer id_grupo;
Grupos  groups;
Usuarious users;

public UsuariousGrupos() {
}

public UsuariousGrupos(Integer id_usuario, Integer id_grupo) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
    this.id_grupo = id_grupo;
}

public Integer getId_grupo() {
    return id_grupo;
}

public void setId_grupo(Integer id_grupo) {
    this.id_grupo = id_grupo;
}

public Integer getId_usuario() {
    return id_usuario;
}

public void setId_usuario(Integer id_usuario) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
}

public Grupos getGroups() {
    return groups;
}

public void setGroups(Grupos groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
}

public Usuarious getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Usuarious users) {
    this.users = users;
}
```

Also, I tested my DAO connection, and they are working fine. I am able to display name/description from my User database table, and Groups database table. However, since my UserGroup table stores just IDs, I am only able to display the IDs. I want to display the name/description of the User/Group that is related to the ID. However, when I do the following:

```
 List<UsuariousGrupos> ugdList = ugd.list() ;
    System.out.println("List of users successfully queried: " + ugdList);
    System.out.println("Thus, amount of usergroups in database is: " + ugdList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < ugdList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Groups in database are: " + ugdList.get(i).getUsers().getNome());
        System.out.println("Users in database are: " + ugdList.get(i).getGroups().getDescricao());
    }
```

I get a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. Apparently, I am unable to access the Users and Groups object from my UserGroup List : / , which leads me to think that I am missing some sort of relationship among the classes.

The null pointer exception occurs at these lines:

```
System.out.println("Groups in database are: " + ugdList.get(i).getUsers().getNome());
System.out.println("Users in database are: " + ugdList.get(i).getGroups().getDescricao()
```

apparently, ugdList.get(i).getUsers() and ugdList.get(i).getGroups() are null.

Any thoughts on this??

Comment: You need to provide the actual exception or more specifically give the line/field that is null.  Even better would be for you to debug your code and figure out which variable is null and edit your question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the name of each user and overload the toString method of the user class like this :

```
public String toString()
{
return String.format(""%s %s", this.name, this.lastName);
}
```

By the way, ugdList.get(i).getUsers().getNome()); seems wrong to me 
But using the toString method applied earlier, you can do this :

```
for (User user : ugdList.get(i).getUsers())
{
printf(user);
}
```

BUT you should test ugdList.get(i).getUsers() by steps before :
check that get(i).getUsers != null then run the loop.

Hope this helps !